# What can make Outlook stop giving appointment reminders?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, reminder

I've been late to two meetings today because Outlook spontaneously stopped giving me reminder popups, even though they're set in the individual scheduled appointments.

[image: Outlook Reminder]

Is there a global setting in Outlook 2003 that I may have accidentally used to disable these reminders?  Where can I look to troubleshoot this?

Comment: What version of Outlook is this? The location of this settings changes frequently. Also, take a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286166

Comment: @William: It's Outlook 2003.  Thanks for reminding me, I updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. On the **Tools** menu, click **Options**.
2. Click the **Other** tab, and then click **Advanced Options**.
3. Click **Reminder Options**.
4. Select or clear the **Display the reminder** check box.

If **Display the reminder** is already selected, follow [this troubleshooting advice on Microsoft's website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286166).

Comment: I don't know how they got turned off to begin with, but about a minute after I ran `outlook /cleanreminders` all of today's appointment reminders popped up.

Comment: The number one cause of dead reminders are addins that corrupt the reminder store. The addin I wrote used to do that. :) But /cleanremnders is the way to go. You should post that as an answer to yourself.